# Limit Max Results after glob sort by time

Tags: php, sorting, glob

I'd like to limit the results returned after I glob the files in a directory and sort them by time. And just in case there are no files in the directory, I'd like to include an `if file exists` phrase as well. Here is the code so far.

```
$list = glob('items/*.html');
usort(
   $list,
   create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);')
);


foreach($list as $file)
{
    include $file;
}
```

Now I'm guessing, I can probably do the `if (file_exists())` part like this:

```
foreach($list as $file)
{
 if (file_exists($file)) {
    include $file;}
}
```

part without throwing errors, but where do I do the count up to a max of 5 or 7?

Answer (score 1):

[glob](http://php.net/glob) returns an empty array when there are no files in the directory. This means, that an [file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists) would be useless, as if you have an value from glob, it would exist.

If glob somehow fails, it will return false. You're script will throw some errors if this happens. Try checking for an array before the foreach using [is_array](http://www.php.net/is_array).

Answer (score 1):

```
$limit=5;
$list = glob('items/*.html');
usort(
   $list,
   create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);')
);  

$list=array_slice($list, 0, $limit);

foreach($list as $file) {
    include $file;
}
```

There is not really a need to do a `file_exists()` query here, because if `glob` found it, it should exist. You might want to do an `is_readable()` though, in this case you could rewrite it like this:

```
$limit=5;
$list = glob('items/*.html');
usort(
   $list,
   create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);')
);  

$i=0;    
foreach($list as $file) {
    if ($i < $limit && is_readable($file)) {
         include $file;
         $i++;
    }
}
```

You might also want to add a check if `glob` failed for some reason.

```
$list = glob('items/*.html');
if ($list===false) {
    /*handle error (or simply $list=array() if you don't care)*/
}
```

- [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- [is_readable()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)

Comment: Hi Bazmegakapa, thanks for the answer. Am I correct in assuming that if I want to add the check to see if glob failed for some reason, that I can do something like: if ($list===false) {} else {usort(...}?

Comment: @Dave Yes, that's one possible approach, perfectly fine.

Comment: Finally had a chance to test it out, as I was having problems with the code that puts the files into the items folder. Works perfect, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try ( for max 5 file to include )

```
foreach($list as $k=>$v)
{
  if($k<5 && file_exists($v))
    include_once $file;
  else
      break;

}
```